# Prevent Linux user from connecting with WinSCP

Tags: ssh, scp, winscp

How can I stop a user from logging on to Linux machine with WinSCP ?

I have set a user up so that when they login via Putty they are presented with an interactive CLI (using Python) and no bash shell.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: perhaps better asked on superuser, but hey: you already got a solution below ;-)

Answer (score 1):

in your sshd_config

Find line that read as follows:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Remove or comment out line by prefixing #:

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Save and close the file. Restart sshd service:

```
# /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

if that does not work then

replace :

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

with :

```
Subsystem sftp /bin/false
```

Comment: While this prevents most users from using WinSCP with the server, it can easily be circumvented. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30753438/850848).

Answer (score 1):

That does not make sense.

If you allow a shell access to the server, you give the user ability to do (almost) anything he/she wants. Blocking WinSCP won't not help and it's not easy anyway.

You can disable the "sftp" subsystem mapping, as shown in the [answer by @Dimi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30741135/850848#30741254). But the user can easily circumvent that by specifying a full path to the `sftp-server` binary in [WinSCP session options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp).

Even if you make any precautions to block user from running the `sftp-server` binary, the user can still revert to the SCP protocol.

Even if you block the `scp` binary too, the user can still modify the files with other methods.

*You should better explain us what is your intent, to get better answers.*